CSRF Prevention Using Signed Cookies And Custom Headers
Recently I was reading about CSRF prevention techniques like Synchronizer Token, Cookie-to-header, and Double Submit Cookie. Cookie-to-header is good for websites using a lot of JavaScript, e.g. SPAs, and Double Submit Cookie eliminates the need to store the CSRF token on the server.
Now, I think I can achieve the best of both worlds with this approach:

User logs in.

Server generates session ID and CSRF token.

Server stores session ID in cookies and makes it http-only.

Server signs CSRF token and stores it in cookies.

Client uses JavaScript to access CSRF token and sends it on every request via AJAX or Fetch via custom header.

Server receives request and checks if CSRF token in cookies is equal to CSRF token in custom header.

If they're equal, user is authenticated. And, of course, session ID is automatically sent.


This is very similar to Double Submit Cookie, the difference is that the server doesn't inject the CSRF token in the HTML or anything like that.
I think this approach has many advantages:

Can be used in SPAs and web apps made with React, Vue, etc..

No need to store CSRF token in the server.

Easy to implement.


I also think it's very secure, because:

Attacker cannot, by any means, change the contents of the CSRF cookie because it's signed. Note that the CSRF cookie is not http-only, so it can be accessed by JavaScript in the client. However, it's also signed, so it's essentially read-only.

Custom headers in requests makes the requests subject to CORS and SOP.


My question is: Is this method secure? I'm not asking for opinions or best practices, I'm asking for objective reasons to use/avoid this approach. What are the pros and cons of this approach? What do you think?

This might be a better fit for the Information Security site.
